# Fixing video container keyframes for live streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-streaming, chromecast, hls

I have a [capture card](https://www.hauppauge.com/pages/products/data_hdpvr2-ge.html) that is handled by [a program](https://hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html) which I intend to run in a Raspberry Pi 3 (I compiled for it) to stream video locally to a Chromecast.
This program is run and spits out video data to stdout in a MPEG-TS container with H.264 and AAC codecs.

I wrote a script which basically segments this to serve a HLS/m3u8 stream:

```
./HDPVR2-testApp | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -f hls -hls_time 2 -hls_flags +delete_segments -hls_list_size 3 -hls_segment_filename /tmp/stream/file_%v_%03d.ts /tmp/stream/out.m3u8
```

This works well on almost any video player except for Chrome(cast) refusing to play the stream. CORS is configured correctly.

While debugging using `chrome://media-internals` the next message appears constantly:

> ISO-BMFF container metadata for video frame indicates that the frame
> is a keyframe, but the video frame contents indicate the opposite.

Investigating this further I came across with the fact that [Chrome is more strict on how to play video formats](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=879734).

By following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1358974/1265337), extracting the H.264 stream and remuxing to a file solved the problem, making both Chrome and Chromecast happy to play the stream. I tested it by using a pipe (`cat fixed-recording.mp4 | ffmpeg -i - ...`) just to make sure that wasn't an issue.

Is there a way I can fix the container keyframes with ffmpeg on the fly? I need to run this in a RPi 3 which means I won't be able to re-encode the video and I would rather not write into the disk big files. This is what I tried:

- Use `-movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe` and a combination of them ([from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762315/how-can-i-record-video-with-ffmpeg-in-iso-bmff-format-ready-for-media-source-ext)).
- Using fragmented MP4 stream instead.
- Extracting the raw streams to two files, but failed because both files need to be written constantly.

Comment: We may be able to fix this in ffmpeg, but the issue is with the tuner's encoder. FFmpeg is not emitting ISOBMFF, but MPEG-TS. The hls player remuxes the received TS into ISOBMFF for MSE.

Comment: Add `-bsf:v extract_extradata,remove_extra=e,dump_extra=k`

Comment: @Gyan that didn't seem to work. Here's a sample recording *if* you want to analyze it: https://files.catbox.moe/2to9vv.ts